# Jest is taking a lot of heap memory with (strings)

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, memory-leaks, ts-jest

As i run all my tests on jest i saw that i have problem with the heap memory (it grows arithmetically).

```js
console.log(45)
```

[Part of the jest tests with GC-tracking](https://pastebin.com/psX2RJKj)

I make a few chrome snapshots and saw that the strings memory allocation goes up on them.

[Firs snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNR5q.png)

[Second snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXjsk.png)

[Third snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYHrK.png)

[Statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD0v6.png)

I am running node 20 and jest 29.7

I expect to lower the heap usage and did not try anything for now